# Android: upload files totally in background

Tags: android, service, background, upload

I have to create a multiple file uploads (3-7 photos), but this upload must be totally managed by the system, so that, even if the user closes the app, it should work until it completes uploading.

A little like Facebook, it upload a photo and if the app is killed: the progress also appears in the notification bar.

I currently use a class, I think FtpClient, which works well but if I close the app it stops. Everything is asynchronous but only for the app, not for the system.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `Service` for this purpose. It will be running on background, and in it you can do all your upload/download work. You can look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) tutorial, and also read more about it from official documentation [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

You can just move all your logic from `Activity`/`Fragment` to `Service`, and it will be do it in background, even if your app is closed.

Comment: but can i add more than a file to the uploader? or i need to create a zip?

Comment: It's all depends of your app logic, and not concerns the Services. You can implement uploading in different ways. You can upload several files on several threads, or in several services, or pack it in zip - it all depend from your purposes and goals that you want to achieve.

Comment: Google recommends Work Manager nowadays: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 2):

This library -
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"

Comment: its a very bad library, spent hours fixing notification channel with java. haven't tried on kotlin.